# Using additional Google APIs in my Glassware (Sharing to g+ accounts)

Tags: python, google-plus, google-mirror-api

I'm trying to share a card ( the html inside it ) from my Glassware using python and the [Python Mirror API Quickstart](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python) code.

```
creds = StorageByKeyName(Credentials, '#####', 'credentials').get()
        plus_service = util.create_service('plus', 'v1', creds)

        moment = {"type":"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
        "target": {
        "id": "target-id-1",
        "type":"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
        "name": "The Google+ Platform",
        "description": "A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!",
        "image": "https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing.png"
                }
        }
        google_request = plus_service.moments().insert(userId='me', collection='vault', body=moment)
        result = google_request.execute()
```

I got this response back:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

I can understand that is a permission problem but my question is, what is the suggested UI to ask to a glass user for G+ permissions?

Furthermore, by adding "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" in the requested permissions I got this:
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault?alt=json returned "Unauthorized">

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are several things that are confusing here, and I'm not entirely sure what is going on. Can you show the code where you are requesting permissions and verify exactly what scope you're requesting? Have you verified that you're actually authorized? And which startup project, exactly, are you using - you've mentioned both Google+ and Glassware, each of which have their own sets of sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get G+ access, you can piggyback on the authorization process that Mirror API uses. Make the following modifications to the [Mirror API Python Quickstart](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python) project:

First, enable the Google+ API in the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) for your project.

Second, in [oauth/hander.py](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python/blob/master/oauth/handler.py#L32), add your G+ scope to the SCOPES list:

```
SCOPES = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.timeline '
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.location '
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile '
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login')
```

Third, revoke your old auth tokens and get fresh ones. Do this by signing out of and signing back into your Quickstart instance's web front end. When you sign in, the sign in page should be updated to list the new Google+ permission:

[image: New Google+ scope listed about Google+]

With these steps, the code you posted should work. Comment if it doesn't and I can help you continue debugging.

Comment: It's also import to note that for `moment.insert` requests you need an additional `request_visible_actions` parameter for the Activity types you want to write during authentication and I'm not sure how that works in combination with `flow_from_clientsecrets`. See https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/#writing_an_app_activity_using_the_google_apis_client_libraries and switch the code sample to Python to see an example of how it is done there.

Comment: Update: you should be able to simple define the additional parameter with `flow.params["request_visible_actions"] = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"` right after creating it in line 42 of the sample: https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python/blob/master/oauth/handler.py#L42

Comment: I got no more error, the actual result is : {u'id': u'Eg0xMzc2NTgxOTMyODQ4GJXv34n_2r7nKTICEBRCBxi-ptG5vw1KEPJcM5xKZRfHSKJ91sYVeyA', u'kind': u'plus#moment', u'type': u'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity', u'target': {u'name': u'The Google+ Platform', u'kind': u'plus#itemScope', u'id': u'target-id-1', u'image': u'https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing.png', u'description': u'A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!'}, u'result': {u'kind': u'plus#itemScope'}} but i cannot see the activity into my profile.